# fabric.js - How to set text width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs, text-alignment

I find that setting `textAlign` to a fabric.js `Text` object is useless because the width of the textfield is automatically assigned to perfectly fit the width of the text.

I can't find anything in the API that lets me set another width. I tried `scaleToWidth`, but it didn't to anything either.

```
this.text = new fabric.Text(this.name, 
{
        fontFamily: 'Calibri Light',
        fontSize: 17,
        backgroundColor: 'blue', // using this to confirm that the width is actually just set to the text width
        textAlign: 'center',
        top: 15,
        scaleToWidth: 1.1,
})
```

I've made it appear in the desired way using a pretty hacky solution.

Quoting from the fabric.js website:

textAlign

*Text align comes useful when working with multiline text. W**ith one-line text, the width of bounding box is always exactly matching that line's width, so there's nothing to align.**
Allowed values are "left", "center", and "right".*

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you ever found an answer in the two years from when you first asked but I had the same problem and was able to find a solve by adding the text object to the canvas then setting it's width and then firing a renderAll() on the canvas.

```
var text = new fabric.Text('sample text', {fill: '#fff', textAlign: 'center'});
canvas.add(text);
text.width = 180;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: You also have to set the text.width = 180 after every change made to the text of the text...

text.set( text: "fred" );
text.width = 180;
canvas.renderAll();

Comment: after 6 years, this is the only work around that i've found.